How to track mouse position inside an image widget after resizing and avoid blind spots in PySide6?
I am trying to print the mouse position only when the user clicks on an image widget in a PySide6 application, but I am facing a couple of issues:

Blind spots: After clicking on the image, I am experiencing some "blind zones" where the mouse position isn't being correctly tracked.
Empty spaces after resizing: When I resize the window, there are empty spaces below the image, and it incorrectly displays that the image is clicked outside of the image bounds.

Here is the relevant code:
from PySide6.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap, Qt, QColor
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QSizePolicy
import cv2

from utils.environment import Environment


class LayoutMouseVisualisation(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LayoutMouseVisualisation, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setStyleSheet("""
            QWidget {
                background-color: black;
            }
        """)
        self.controller = ControllerMouseVisualisation(self)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.image_label = QLabel()
        self.update_img(self.controller.get_teeth_image())
        self.image_label.mousePressEvent = self.mousePressEvent
        self.layout.addWidget(self.image_label)

    def update_img(self, img):
        height, width, channel = img.shape
        bytes_per_line = 3 * width
        # noinspection all
        self.q_img = QImage(img.data, width, height, bytes_per_line, QImage.Format_RGB888)
        pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(self.q_img)
        self.image_label.setPixmap(pixmap)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        x = event.pos().x()
        y = event.pos().y()

        img_width, img_height, _ = self.controller.get_image_shape()

        label_rect = self.image_label.geometry()
        label_x = label_rect.x()
        label_y = label_rect.y()

        print(f"Label geometry: x={label_x}, y={label_y}, width={label_rect.width()}, height={label_rect.height()}")

        # Check if the click is inside the image area
        if label_x <= x <= img_width + label_x and label_y <= y <= img_height + label_y:
            print(f"Mouse clicked inside the image at x: {x}, y: {y}")
        else:
            print(f"Mouse clicked outside the image area at x: {x}, y: {y}")

class ControllerMouseVisualisation:
    def __init__(self, view):
        self.view = view
        self.teeth_image = cv2.imread(Environment.resource_path('static/images/teeth.jpg'))
        self.colored_image = self.teeth_image.copy()

    def get_teeth_image(self):
        return self.colored_image

    def get_image_shape(self):
        return self.teeth_image.shape

Initially, I thought the problem was related to the label's size policies, but after some testing, I realized that this isn't the case. Using localPos() also didn't help.

The incorrect click position is caused by the fact that you're only considering the QLabel geometry, but not that of the image (which follows the alignment property of the label and defaults to left-vertical center), but since the label is the only widget in the layout, it "expands" whenever there is space left around it, while still keeping the original image size and aligning it in the available space. You must consider the actual image geometry relative to that of the label. See the first duplicated post for a more detailed explanation.

The "blind spots" you mention are probably those caused by your "monkey patching" of mousePressEvent(), which is also corresponds to an override for LayoutMouseVisualisation. This means that the x and y you get from the event will be relative to that of the label if clicked inside it, or relative to the top level widget if clicking outside of the label, since layouts always have a default margins (normally 10-11 pixels). To clarify how this happens, change the stylesheet to QWidget { background: gray; } QLabel { background: black; } and then click slightly inside or outside of the »

» label: you will see that the x and y positions will not be consistent, because the receiver of the event is not the same. The above is a perfect example of the reasons for which: 1. you should never monkey patch, unless you really know what you're doing (at the very least, you should use a different function name to avoid conflicts), and it's almost always better to use a subclass and override its own methods instead; 2. the generic QWidget selector in QSS (as much as declaring generic properties without selectors) should normally be avoided for containers and complex widgets.
